# Traveling from Mexico City to Egypt with my American Passport is that possible?

Tags: paperwork, us-citizens, mexico, egypt

i'm an American citizen and I need to know if I can travel from Mexico City,to Egypt with my American passport?

Comment: Why do you think you would not be able to?

Comment: Barring abnormal circumstances, yes.  Is there a specific reason you're asking this?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with [tag:rome] and [tag:jordan]? Are those places that you plan to pass through on your way from Mexico to Egypt, or is there some other relevance to them?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can.

You seem to think that there can be restrictions on what flight routes you can take on a specific passport. **There is no such thing**